# Netezza SQL to join a table if that table contains relevant data

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to join tables based on certain columns being within a specified time range. I've tried several methods and haven't been able to solve this.

I start with a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM admin.mktdmtunit c
WHERE c.unitid IN ('2756')
AND c.calledofftime between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
    AND to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

that returns 1 row.

I then add another table:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM admin.mktdmtunit c
    INNER JOIN admin.mktmanualdispatch_all mrd 
    ON c.unitid = mrd.unitid
    where c.unitid in ('2756')
    AND (c.calledofftime between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
        and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
        OR mrd.effectivetime  between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd           hh:mi:ss') 
            and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'))
```

that returns 4 lines based on 4 entries in the mrd table for that unitid. But none of these are relevant to that date so I'd like to not see that information.

So I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM admin.mktdmtunit c
where c.unitid in ('2756')
AND c.calledofftime between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
    and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
OR (exists(SELECT mrd.effectivetime 
    FROM admin.mktmanualdispatch_all mrd 
    WHERE mrd.effectivetime  between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
        and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
    AND c.unitid = mrd.unitid)
```

but this gives an error saying that it expects a "," before the "mrd.unitid" in the last line.

So I also tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM admin.mktdmtunit c
INNER JOIN admin.mktmanualdispatch_all mrd 
    ON
    mrd.effectivetime  between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
        and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
    AND c.unitid = mrd.unitid
where c.unitid in ('2756')
AND c.calledofftime between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
    and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

but this doesn't return any lines.

So to be clear, what I am wanting from this specific query is 1 row that has the information based on c.calledofftime and no information pulled in from the other table since there is no relevant data based on mrd.effective time.
Thanks

Comment: So essentially you're looking to join `mktdmtunit` with `mktmanualdispatch_all`, for unit id 2756,  where the called off time is between 12/5 at 5 am and 12/6 at 5 am, and the dispatch effective time is also between 12/5 at 5 am and 12/6 at 5 am?

Comment: Well mktdmtunit is the "main" table but otherwise you are correct. I actually have solved this by making the inner join on my last bit of code a left outer join. It won't let me post an actual answer since I'm new here.

Comment: You should have enough privilege to be able to submit an answer to your question now.

Comment: Well-written question. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

It has already been answered by the poster, but yeah, left join the second table and include the mrd.effectivetime criteria in the join logic so you'll receive NULLs if none exist. This will allow you to maintain your core information from the primary table.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm just going to refer to your "Dec 5th 2012 5am to Dec 6th 2012 5am" 
condition as "= Dec 5th" for brevity.

The second query: the OR on the second last line means that it will join the tables 
on unitid and limit results to unitid = 2756 and further limit rows to those 
where EITHER mktdmtunit.calledofftime OR mktmanualdispatch_all.effectivetime = Dec 5th
(or they both = Dec 5th).  You get 4 rows returned because there are 4 rows in mktmanualdispatch_all with unitid = 2756.

The fourth query AND's these datetime conditions: returned rows must have BOTH  calledofftime = Dec 5th value AND effectivetime = Dec 5th.  I am not sure which of the EITHER or BOTH logic you wanted, but I think it was the EITHER, because you seem to be expecting this to return some rows.

The syntax error for the 3rd query - I think it is because you are missing a closing parenthesis.  You open two: "OR (exists(SELECT mrd.effectivetime ..." but only close 
one: "... AND c.unitid = mrd.unitid)"

I suggest

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM admin.mktdmtunit c
 where c.unitid in ('2756')
   AND (   (c.calledofftime between to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01',
                                                 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
                                and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00',
                                                 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
           )
        OR (exists (SELECT mrd.effectivetime 
                      FROM admin.mktmanualdispatch_all mrd 
                     WHERE (mrd.effectivetime  between 
                             to_timestamp('2012-12-05 05:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
                         and to_timestamp('2012-12-06 05:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
                           )
                       AND c.unitid = mrd.unitid
                    )
           )
       ) ;
```

This will return all columns of mktdmtunit where unitid is 2756 and either calledofftime is in the Dec 5th datetime range, 
OR where mktmanualdispatch_all.effectivetime is in the Dec 5th datetime range,